# high resource usage program stalls/crashes linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, openmp, fedora, freeze

I have a program that reads about 1000 images and creates a statistical summary of their contents.  Each image is processed in its own thread using OpenMP, and I have the thread limit set to match my number of processors.

Until about two weeks ago, the program ran fine.  Now, however, if I run the program more than once, my system slows down and eventually freezes up.

In order to troubleshoot, I wrote the simple code listed below that emulates what my program is doing.  This code will freeze my system, just as my original program does, after trying to read only a few files at line 35.

I ran the program, successively reverting to an earlier kernel after each failure, and found that it fails with all 3.6 kernels up to version 3.6.8.

However, when I go back to kernel 3.5.6, it works.

test.cc:

```
  1 #include <cstdio>
  2 #include <iostream>
  3 #include <vector>
  4 #include <unistd.h>
  5 
  6 using namespace std;
  7 
  8 int main ()
  9 {
 10     // number of files
 11     const size_t N = 1000;
 12     // total system memory
 13     const size_t MEM = sysconf (_SC_PHYS_PAGES) * sysconf (_SC_PAGE_SIZE);
 14     // file size
 15     const size_t SZ = MEM/N;
 16 
 17     // create temp filenames
 18     vector<string> fn (N);
 19     for (size_t i = 0; i < fn.size (); ++i)
 20         fn[i] = string (tmpnam (NULL));
 21 
 22     // write a bunch of files to disk
 23     for (size_t i = 0; i < fn.size (); ++i)
 24     {
 25         vector<char> a (SZ);
 26         FILE *fp = fopen (fn[i].c_str (), "wb");
 27         fwrite (&a[0], a.size (), 1, fp);
 28         clog << fn[i] << " written" << endl;
 29     }
 30 
 31     // read a bunch of files from disk
 32 #pragma omp parallel for
 33     for (size_t i = 0; i < fn.size (); ++i)
 34     {
 35         vector<char> a (SZ);
 36         FILE *fp = fopen (fn[i].c_str (), "rb");
 37         fread (&a[0], a.size (), 1, fp);
 38         clog << fn[i] << " read" << endl;
 39     }
 40 
 41     return 0;
 42 }
```

Makefile:

```
  1 a:$
  2     g++ -fopenmp -Wall -o test -g test.cc$
  3     ./test$
```

My question is: What is different about kernel 3.6 that would cause this program to fail, but does not cause it to fail in version 3.5?

Answer (score 1):

Without going through the code, if you want to set some limits to your processes, have a look at [cgroups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups) for limiting resource usage.

As for the freezing - you are trying to read/write GBs of data to disk at once. Given the speeds of ~100MB/s of today's hard-drives, I would expect a freeze at the time the kernel decides to flush the caches to the disk - which will probably occur as soon as you try to read a reasonably sized chunk of data from the disk under memory pressure (since you allocated lots of memory, the space for caches is limited).

You can try to `mmap()` the files or change kernel I/O scheduler.

Comment: Your comment about changing the kernel I/O scheduler is useful.  I will try that.

I can believe that the kernel would hiccup when it tries to flush its disk caches, but, as I stated, the whole system freezes.  It remains in this state for hours and eventually requires a reboot.  That indicates a more serious problem in my mind.

Comment: @jsp yes indeed. It might also be useful to enable the `SysRq` facility to get some idea about what's going on in the system. Plus you might want to enable network console (or use serial cable if available) to send the log to another computer for inspection. If there's some problem on kernel level you should be able to see it in kernel log. Trying cgroups might also help you locate the problem. Or run the application in a virtual machine and see what freezes: VM or host.

Comment: I tried changing IO scheduling algorithms, with no luck.  Maybe I should not have said 'freezes' because numlock responds and I am able to ssh in and examine log files, etc.  I see nothing of interest in /var/log/messages or ~/.xsession-errors.  When it is in this state, certain programs will run, others run very slowly, and some don't respond at all -- like I've run out of memory.  Note that I changed the original question to indicate that none of these symptoms occur on 3.5.X kernels.  The problem only occurs on 3.6.X kernels.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't look in deep at your code, but I realised some bad practices (at least, I thing they're) :

- First, the `critical` section inside the openmp loop. That is a synchronism point, and putting it in every iteration sounds kind of problematic to me. Since each thread must be sure no other one has entered there, probably the overhead that synchronism introduces increases with the number of threads.
- Second: I am not very used to C++, but I guess that every time `vector<char> a (SZ)` is executed memory is allocated (and freed at the end of the block). Excuse me if I am wrong. Since you know beforehand the value of SZ, you'll better allocate a `vector<vector<char> >` with as many elements as threads before the parallel region. Then, in the parallel region, you'd make each thread access its `vector<char>`.

Comment: The critical section is just to prevent the log messages from overwriting one another.  I can remove it if you like -- makes no difference.

Comment: ah, okey. So I guess that you tested the performance in a version without that critical region. However be careful with allocating and freeing resources inside a loop such as that one. Better allocate all the possible memory just once, and free it after the loop.